# PHP takes three numbers, prints only numbers that are even + sorted

Tags: php, arrays, numbers

I'm new here!

With `$_POST`, PHP takes three numbers, prints only numbers that are even and needs to be sorted. I suck at this, but I tried here's my code:

```
<body>

<form name="getallen" action="111.php" form method="POST">
Geef drie getallen in.</br>
Getallen: 
<input type="text" name="getallen" maxlength=""/></br>
<input type="text" name="getallen" maxlength=""/></br>
<input type="text" name="getallen" maxlength=""/></br>
<input type="submit" value="controle"/>
</form>

</body>


<?php


$_POST ["getallen"];


if (is_array($_POST['getallen'])) { 
echo 'Resultaat: <br />'; 
foreach ($_POST['getallen'] as $r) {
sort($_POST['getallen']); 
echo "<i>$r</i><br />";
} 
}else {
    echo "Gelieve juiste getallen in te geven";
    }


?>
```

Comment: Strange things, there are plenty of them. What's lonely `$_POST['getallen']` doing here? What's `$r`, and why are you trying to sort an array at _each_ iteration?

Answer (score 1):

Your input form should be array

```
<input type="text" name="getallen[]" value="" /><br />
<input type="text" name="getallen[]" value="" /><br />
<input type="text" name="getallen[]" value="" /><br />
```

and now try print_r($_POST); or you can loop with

```
foreach ( $_POST as $r ) {
    echo $r.'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot wrong with your code. I would recommend brushing up on the basics of PHP and HTML forms, but you probably want something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="getallen[]" /><br />
<input type="text" name="getallen[]" /><br />
<input type="text" name="getallen[]" /><br />
```

PHP:

```
$sortedArray = sort($_POST['getallen']);
foreach($sortedArray as $r){
  if(($r % 2) == 0){
    echo "<i>$r</i><br />";
  }
  else{
    echo "Gelieve juiste getallen in te geven";
  }
}
```